# How to send HTTP_POST and receive results

Tags: php

I'd like to send an HTTP_POST request to a third party website, and receive the results in a way that I can check the results against some parameters. I am very new to PHP so am somewhat lost.

The page I want to query is http://modelaircraft.org/membership/verify. I'd like to send the POST request with a LAST NAME and AMA NUMBER that I can get from the user on my site in WPForms. When the query returns, if I have a valid response (date on or after 12/31/2023), the user should be taken to a specific page on my site. If the response is NOT valid, I'd like to notify the user and stay on the current page.

If you'd like to test, you can use LEE and 759314 as parameters to see what a valid response might look like.

I have a form currently on my site that gets the name and number from the user, and then links to the second page, without any validation.  This validation is the piece I am missing.

Any help would be appreciated.

MY SITE'S PAGE:

http://tst.pvmac.com/ama-verification

You can go here and kind of see what I am talking about...

Answer (score 0):

https://www.modelaircraft.org/membership/verify is an HTML form, but it makes a AJAX request to https://www.modelaircraft.org/membership/verify?ajax_form=1&_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax to actually get the data. So, it'd be ideal to make a request directly there instead.

I don't think there's a practical (and possibly TOS-compliant) way to do that, though, because their form generates a `form_build_id` NONCE, and the handler validates it. It doesn't seem like the API is meant for public use.

Technically, you could make a GET request to https://www.modelaircraft.org/membership/verify to get a nonce, and then make the request with it, but that's probably not kosher. You should probably talk to them and ask them to provide a public API instead.

If they do that, then this code is roughly what you would need. It's impossible to get it exact until they provide the public API, though, so you'd need to adapt it once they do. This is enough to give you a general idea of the WordPress and PHP functions you could use, though.

```
// Mimic the AJAX request at https://www.modelaircraft.org/membership/verify
parse_str(
    'form_id=membership_verify_form&_triggering_element_name=op&_triggering_element_value=Submit&_drupal_ajax=1&ajax_page_state%5Btheme%5D=nt_ama&ajax_page_state%5Btheme_token%5D=&ajax_page_state%5Blibraries%5D=ama%2Fama.form_validations%2Cclassy%2Fbase%2Cclassy%2Fmessages%2Ccore%2Fdrupal.ajax%2Ccore%2Finternal.jquery.form%2Ccore%2Fnormalize%2Celfinder%2Fdrupal.elfinder%2Cextlink%2Fdrupal.extlink%2Cformtips%2Fformtips%2Cformtips%2Fhoverintent%2Cnt_ama%2Fentity-print%2Cnt_ama%2Fnt_ama%2Comega%2Fomega%2Cresponsive_menu%2Fresponsive_menu.config%2Cresponsive_menu%2Fresponsive_menu.styling%2Csimple_background_image_formatter%2Fglobal-styling%2Csystem%2Fbase%2Ctb_megamenu%2Ftheme.tb_megamenu',
    $args
);

// This probably won't work because `form_build_id` appears to be a unique value generated by Drupal
$args['form_build_id'] = 'form-pAoNX6EXlS_MsxmfsanTAyq8VXBKDqqm9fvgvAntWSQ';
$args['ama_number']    = 759314;
$args['last_name']     = 'LEE';

$response = wp_remote_post(
    'https://www.modelaircraft.org/membership/verify?ajax_form=1&_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax',
    $args
);

if ( is_wp_error( ( $response ) ) ) {
    throw new Exception( $response->get_error_message() );
}

$body = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );

if ( ! $body ) {
    throw new Exception( 'Request failed' );
}

$error_message = trim( strip_tags( $body[0]->data ) ) ?? '';

if ( $error_message ) {
    throw new Exception( $error_message );
}

$success_message = $body[1]->data;
preg_match( '(is valid until )(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})', $success_message, $matches );
$date = $matches[2];

if ( strtotime( $date ) >= strtotime( '12/31/2023' ) ) {
    wp_redirect( 'your success URL' );
    exit;
} else {
    echo 'Error: date not valid';
}
```

If you run the code now, you'll see that their API is returning an error message because the NONCE validation fails.